# Normal Bundle is Trivial

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles

how can I show the normal bundle $$\nu(\mathbb S^n):=\bigcup_{p\in\mathbb S^n} T_p\mathbb R^{n+1}/T_p\mathbb S^n, $$ is a trivial bundle? Any help will be valuable.. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

The normal bundle of the standard embedding of $S^n$ in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ has a nowhere vanishing section (the unit outward normal to the sphere, $\displaystyle \frac{\mathbf{x}}{\|\mathbf{x}\|}$). So you just need to show that a nowhere vanishing section of a rank $1$ vector bundle can be used to construct an isomorphism of the bundle with the trivial bundle.

If you already know this fact, then you're done. If you don't know it, the proof is a simple exercise.

This is a special case of a more general fact:

> If $E \longrightarrow M$ is a rank $k$ vector bundle and $s_1, \dots, s_k$ are sections of $E$ such that $\{s_1(p), \dots, s_k(p)\}$ is a basis for that fiber $E_p$ for all $p \in M$, then $E$ is isomorphic to the trivial rank $k$ bundle over $M$.

Comment: You mean I must construct an isomorphism between $\nu(\mathbb S^n)$ and $\mathbb S^{n}\times \mathbb R$ with the aid of the nowhere vanishing section?

Comment: Yes. A specific isomorphism $f: S^n \times \Bbb R \longrightarrow \nu(S^n)$ is given by $f(p, t) = t \frac{\mathbf{x}}{\|\mathbf{x}\|}$.

Comment: what I thought was defining $\phi:\nu(\mathbb S^n)\rightarrow \mathbb S^n\times \mathbb R$ by $$v+T_p\mathbb S^n\mapsto (p, \langle p, v\rangle)$$ I guess it works, what you think @Henry?

Comment: @PtF: You want to map $v \in T_p S^n$ to $(p, \langle p, v \rangle)$, where $\langle p, v \rangle$ is the dot product of $p$ and $v$? This won't work, because for any $p \in S^n$, considered as a vector in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$, and any $v \in T_p S^n$, also considered as a vector in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$, $\langle p, v \rangle = 0$.

Comment: no, $\nu(\mathbb S^n)$ is an union of quotient spaces so I want to map the classe $[v]\in \nu_p(\mathbb S^n)$ to $(p, \langle v, p\rangle)$ and it works fine, I wrote a formal proof for this.. Later I'll post here..

Comment: Could you post the proof here @PtF?

Comment: @avati91 I've posted the answer =)

Answer (score 6):

We will construct a vector bundle isomorphism between $\mathcal{V}(\mathbb S^n)$ and the trivial vector bundle $\mathbb S^n\times \mathbb R$.

Define $\Phi:\nu(\mathbb S^n)\rightarrow \mathbb S^n\times \mathbb R$ setting $$[v]\in \nu_p(\mathbb S^n)\mapsto (p, \langle v, p\rangle).$$ Notice $\Phi$ is well defined. In fact, if $u\in [v]$ then $u-v\in T_p\mathbb S^n$ so that,
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle (p, 0)=( p, \langle u-v, p\rangle)=(p, \langle u, p\rangle-\langle v, p\rangle),
\end{align*}
hence,
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle \Phi([u])=(p, \langle u, p\rangle)=(p, 0)+(p, \langle v, p\rangle)=(p, \langle v, p\rangle)=\phi([v]).
\end{align*}
Now define $\Psi: \mathbb{S}^n\times \mathbb R\rightarrow \nu(\mathbb S^n)$ setting $$(q, t)\mapsto [tq]\in \nu_q(\mathbb S^n).$$ Then,
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle (\Phi\circ \Psi)(p, t)=\Phi([tp])=(p, \langle tp, p\rangle)=(p, t\langle p, p\rangle)=(p, t),
\end{align*}
whereas,
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle (\Psi\circ \Phi)([v])=\Psi(p, \langle v, p\rangle)=[\langle v, p\rangle p]=[v],
\end{align*} 
for $v-\langle v, p\rangle p\in T_p\mathbb S^n$ since,
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle \langle p, v-\langle v, p\rangle p\rangle=\langle p, v\rangle-\langle v, p\rangle \langle p, p\rangle=\langle p, v\rangle-\langle v, p\rangle=0.
\end{align*}
It is an exercise to check $\Phi$ is vector bundle morphism. The linearity on the fibers follows from the linearity of the scalar product $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$.